# Converting Blogger Template to Regular Site

Tags: blogger

is it possible to convert a blogger template to a regular site with own domain. I already have the domain, but how do I upload the same site from my blogger to my regular site? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For the Template:

Blogger templates use Blogger API and codes are different accordingly.Accordingly you would have to design a new template.

For Posts

It would depends of the framework/CMS of your new website development system for the purposing of exporting from Blogger and importing to your new system.For example,For migration of blogger posts to wordpress posts,we have many tools available online